# How to activate/install SSL Certificate on Custom PHP Page

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am new to SSL, but i have search the internet to enable the SSL in Joomla-based website which is successful.

But there is subdomains in which i created custom PHP pages and want install the SSL Certificate on the pages i have created.

Please is there any guide to go about it.

Thank you

Comment: PHP is the interpreter running in your server. You need to install SSL certificate on the web server, not PHP.

Comment: Yeah, i install the Certificate on the server and activated it in the Joomla-based main website. but want activate the SSL Certificate on the Custom PHP pages I have created in the **subdomain**

Comment: you have different offers for SSL certificates, some cover subdomains, others don't, you have to check that first

Comment: Okay let me check it first. But i thought there is some workaround for it to work on the subdomains

Comment: Make sure your cert is a wildcard cert. The cheapest cert usually supports only ONE domain (not including subdomain).

Comment: Be aware, that free SSL certificates does not cover wildcard subdomains. Your options are: 1) Expensive certificate that will work with subdomains; 2) One free certificate per subdomain; 3) Self-signed certificate that will provide warning to end-users.
Free certificates is a separate topic.

Comment: I understand this, will verify and retry it. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You don't install an SSL Certificate on a specific page. 
You install it on the web server, which is probably either `apache2` or `nginx`. 
Try installing it there or contact your webhost/admin.

Answer (score -1):

```
#Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: There is no way to configure SSL certificates in .htaccess, this must be done in the server configuration. The given code (which lacks an explanation!) does not configure certificates, but only adds a redirection

Comment: To force your site to always use HTTPS, add the following line in your .htaccess file